# How do I successfully invoke a URL, that requests login through pop up?

Tags: javascript, powershell, authentication, url

I am trying to login to page using PowerShell, as I enter the URL a pop up requests login. I tried to enter the credentials using `Headers` it did not work, tried using `Cred` did not work, also I tried to check source code to find if I could login through  `DOM` but could not find anything. Can anyone let me know how could I login?

I think the pop up is enabled by something like `Javascript` and the values are directly passed to it.

[image]

```
$user = "uuuu"
$pass = "pppp"

# Build auth header
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user, $pass)))

# Set proper headers
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add('Authorization',('Basic {0}' -f $base64AuthInfo))

$uri = "https://somepage.com/xxx"

Invoke-WebRequest -Headers $headers -Uri $uri

$cred = Get-Credential
Invoke-WebRequest  -Uri $bt_uri -Credential $cred
```

Comment: Have you tried the [`-Credential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7#parameters) parameter?

Comment: @iRon yeah, I tried it, updated the code.

Comment: I think you need to save the session the first time you do it using the `SessionVariable` parameter, on subsequent calls you can use the variable used in `WebSession`. See the [`-SessionVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7#parameters). Example 2 [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7#examples).

Comment: @Ash I am unable to login even for once

Comment: If you put the credentials in the pop up box yourself just the first time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to identify the type of Authentication that server has, I was trying HTTP authentication using header but later found that server is actually using NTLM Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You’re going to need a .htaccess and .htpasswd file. More information here https://youtu.be/QYAWJjb6DKI